# Datatables hide column doesn't work when stateSave true

Tags: datatables

The Datatables feature to hide columns using `visible: false` is ignored when `stateSave` is `true`. Does anyone have a fix or workaround for this?

Columns 1 and 2 should be hidden but are not. If you set `stateSave` to `false`, then they correctly get hidden. I have a JSfiddle test case [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4769fvxr/).

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       stateSave: true,
                "columnDefs": [
                        { "visible": false, "targets": [1, 2] }
                ]       
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working just fine, see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/dagxecjr/).

Comment: That is bizarre. It's working now and it wasn't at the time I posted! I'll need to investigate further. Thank you.